# anchor tag not working because of javascript

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I am using javascript for fullpage scroll.I found it here on stackoverflow,but my anchor navigation is not working.
Let's assume I have 4 different sections:
1-HOME
2-ABOUT
3-WORK
4-CONTACT

When I am on HOME section,and click on the CONTACT anchor tag in menu,it is not allowing me to skip sections,but it just goes one by one until it reaches it.
How to disable this option?

```
var debug = false;

// setup default index of 0
var index = 0;

// setup scrolling flag
var scrolling = false;

// cache a few elements for reference
var win = $( window );
var body = $( 'body' );
var container = $( '.container' );

// setup a few more variables for future use
var lastTop = 0;
var current, offset;

// bind scroll event
win.on( 'scroll', function( ev ) {
// prevent the default event
ev.preventDefault();
// check to make sure we don't fire the scroll multiple times
if ( debug ) console.log( scrolling, 'scrolling' );
if ( scrolling ) return;

// set the scrolling flag to true
scrolling = true;

// run the update function
updateActive();

// clear the scrolling flag to allow the user to access the next element
setTimeout( function() { scrolling = false; }, 500 );

// update a few variables for the next interaction
current = container.find( '.inner[data-index='+index+']' );
offset = current.offset();
lastTop = offset.top;

// handle the animation
body.animate(
    { scrollTop : offset.top + 'px' }
);

});

function updateActive() {
// get the current top offset
var top = win.scrollTop();
// determine which direction we are scrolling
if ( top > lastTop ) { 
    // down
    if ( debug ) console.log( 'scrolling down' );
    // let make sure we aren't on the last element
    if ( debug ) console.log( index, $( '.inner' ).length );
    if ( index == $( '.inner' ).length  ) {
        if ( debug ) console.log( 'on last element, nothing to do' );
        return;
    }

    // update index & top
    if ( debug ) console.log( index, 'index before' );
    index++;
    if ( debug ) console.log( index, 'index after' );
    lastTop = top;

} else { 
    // up
    if ( debug ) console.log( 'scrolling up' );
    // let make sure we aren't on the first element
    if ( ! index ) {
        if ( debug ) console.log( 'on first element, nothing to do' );
        return;
    }

    // update index & top
    if ( debug ) console.log( index, 'index before' );
    index--;
    if ( debug ) console.log( index, 'index after' );
    lastTop = top;

}
}
```

Comment: maybe you should remove the animation `body.animate(
    { scrollTop : offset.top + 'px' }
);`

Comment: @taha yes,but when I do that,I don't have full page scrolling anymore,just the regular one.